# SQL query error (correlated subquery with skip-level correlations is not supported )

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have a following sql query which run at:

*PostgreSQL 9.5.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit*

but **not** at:

*PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.5.4 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2*

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT AVG(dur)
    FROM data t
    WHERE t.id = t1.id AND 
        t.id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM data t2
                    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                    ORDER BY dur
                    DESC LIMIT 10)) as avgdur
FROM data t1 
WHERE t1.b<10000
ORDER BY avgdur 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I get the following error:
ERROR:  correlated subquery with skip-level correlations is not supported (subselect.c:394)

How should i modify the query?

Comment: see these link, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426221/postgresql-correlated-sub-query-fail

Comment: `WHERE t2.id = t1.id)) as avgdur` -->> `WHERE t2.id = t.id)) as avgdur` But the query can probably be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems lies in `WHERE t2.id = t1.id`. You can use in a subquery the query at the parent level but not at upper levels. So here you have 3 levels:

1. t1
2. t
3. t2

You can use t from the "t2 subquery" (query where t2 is in the FROM clause) and you can use t1 in your "t subquery". BUT you CANNOT use t1 from your "t2 subquery".

A fix could be to use `WHERE t2.id = t.id)) as avgdur`.

Some infos here : http://www.greenplumdba.com/correlated-subqueries-csqs-in-greenplum

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as you're simply trying to do a group by in a different way...

```
SELECT id, AVG(dur) as avgdur
FROM data t1 
WHERE t1.b<10000
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY avgdur 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: yes, but i have to do more things, i just simplified the question, i have to find the id where the 5 max element average is the maximum

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal Query Optimizer (available in 4.3.5) supports queries with multi-level correlation. To enable Pivotal Query Optimizer, run the following commands.

set optimizer =on;

I would encourage you to upgrade to the latest GPDB version of 4.3.8 which has several improvements and bug fixes.

Let me know if this helps!